# I want to integrate Xero with my WordPress and want to retrieve invoices data with invoice id

Tags: php, wordpress, xero-api

I want to integrate Xero with my WordPress and want to retrieve invoices data with invoice id . I referred some docs but they said to use composer but in WordPress I don't have composer to install library's. So some one help me out how to integrate xero with wordpress and retrieve data I have all credentials like secret id and client id .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Composer is just a way to install dependencies. You can still download the Xero PHP library and add it to your plugin folder. Then you can keep following the Xero PHP guide.

Comment: There is no Wordpress native integration with Xero, but as wordpress is PHP based, you can use the PHP SDK: https://github.com/XeroAPI/xero-php-oauth2